# mongoDB listCollections() returns empty if nameOnly is set to true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I am using nestJS to try and get a list of collections that exist under a database. However, if I try to use the option `{ nameOnly: true }` I get an empty array.

Below is the code I have for getting the collection names:

```
  @Get(':client_name/listCollections')
  async collections(@Param('client_name') client_name) {
    let arrayOfCollections;
    const db = await this.databaseService.connectToDatabase(client_name);

    try {
      arrayOfCollections = await db
        .listCollections({ nameOnly: true })
        .toArray();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
    if (arrayOfCollections) {
      return arrayOfCollections;
    }
  }
```

If I remove `{ nameOnly: true }` then I get the full list but as this puts a lock on the database and returns extra info I don't need I'd like to avoid using it if possible.

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listCollections/) does not mention any `{ readOnly: true }` parameter. Maybe you mean `db.getCollectionInfos().filter(x => x.info.readonly)`

Comment: Sorry, I have meant `{ nameOnly: true }`. I have updated my post. Also `db.getCollectionInfos()` is for mongo shell. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64482388/10727547

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just providing this option as the query of the method, all you need to do is rewrite it with an empty query:

```
arrayOfCollections = await db
    .listCollections({}, { nameOnly: true })
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that was the issue. Thank you! Wonder why this doesn't happen with `listDatabases()`. As I'm doing the same thing there ```arrayOfDatabases = await adminDatabase.listDatabases({
        nameOnly: true,
      });```

Comment: It depends on how the nodejs driver implemented the function, usually you have to check the exact implementation for these "admin" commands.